# Mysql multiple insert statement not adding all records

Tags: mysql

I'm inserting a max of 3000 records and for this I just wrote a single query like

```
insert into p_code (id_user_staff,user_id,postalcode,dropDownGroup) 
values 
(187,51,'AB10',1), 
(187,51,'AB11',1), 
(187,51,'AB12',1), 
(187,51,'AB13',1), 
(187,51,'AB14',1), 
(187,51,'AB15',1), 
(187,51,'AB16',1), 
(187,51,'AB21',1), .........3000
```

This seems to be working fine, but it's not adding all records, many of them are missed. I've also tried the same with each single query in for loop but this also is not adding all records.

Comment: You should check if a error has occured.

Comment: Do you have any primary/unique key constraint on this table? You seem to be repeating the same values for what I guess would be the primary key(s). Also, from `AB16` you go to `AB21`. Maybe you don't have all records listed, which makes you think they are not added?

Comment: You should check for the design of your table, you have only the postalcode field is filled with new data in your records, id_uder_staff,user_id,dropDownGroup are the same for the 3000 records you want to insert.is there any primary key in this table???

Comment: Do you have any triggers on insert?

Comment: Don't forget to commit !

Comment: Guys, there is a ID field which is only primary key auto_incerment field and I've not taken it into this insert statement. Except this there is no foreign key, unique key or any key. No triggers too. SHOW WARNINGS and SHOW ERRORS are also not showing any error or warning after running the bare insert query in console. Frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried the same with each single query in for loop but this also is not adding all records.

Obviously the insert statement is fine then.
There is some constraint on the table that is preventing some values from being inserted.

This is either a unique or primary key. On one or more of the fields:
`id_user_staff, user_id, dropDownGroup`

Or a foreign key constaint that is not met on an insert.

Or a trigger that fires `before` the insert and that generates an error, thereby preventing the insert from being finalized.

If you do the big insert statement, you can use:

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Afterwards that will give you the exact error(s) which is stopping the insert(s).

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html

Comment: I've skipped the primary key in this insert statement as I've ID as a primary key auto_increment and I'm not adding any value in that ID field. Also there is no trigger or foreign key implementation. This is strange :(